# Saving my rails object from an array of values sourced form a csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i'm currently trying to update attributes via a csv upload.

My method looks like this:

```
def upload_csv
  CSV.parse(params[:file].read, headers: true) do |row|
    foo = Foo.find_by_id(row.to_hash["id"])
    row.to_hash.each do |v|
       if Foo.new.has_attribute?(v[0]) && v[0] != "id"
         foo.update_attributes()
       end
     end
  end
end
```

When it jumps into where I want to update my attributes, i'm getting an array that looks like this:

```
["bar", "22"]
```

How can I save that value to my foo object?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so reading you're code I'm concluding that your problem is really that you have a CSV that may contain some fields that are not in your model:

```
def upload_csv
  excluded = %w/id created_at updated_at/
  CSV.new( params[:file], headers: true) do |row|
    rh = row.to_hash
    foo = Foo.find_by id: rh['id']
    foo.update! rh.slice(*foo.attribute_names).except(*excluded)
  end
end
```

Note that I'm assuming `params[:file]` is an uploaded file from a form, in which case it's an `IO` object, and so can be passed into `CSV.new` directly (no need to read it all into memory and pass it to `CSV.parse`).